# Dockerfile compile in local machine but fails in docker hub for automated build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, raspberry-pi3, dockerhub, alpine-linux

I am trying to make an automated build docker image in docker hub by linking my [github repo](https://github.com/swapnil96/docker-swarm-arm-socat) which contains a Dockerfile. This image is for Raspberry Pi 3(can be seen in Dockerfile). While the Dockerfile works fine in the **Raspberry Pi** it give error in **x86_64 GNU/Linux** machine and also in **Docker hub** it fails to compile. Here is the log from Docker hub. The final error is same in docker hub and x86_64 GNU/Linux machine.

```
Building in Docker Cloud's infrastructure...
Cloning into '.'...
KernelVersion: 4.4.0-79-generic
Arch: amd64
BuildTime: 2017-03-28T19:26:53.326478373+00:00
ApiVersion: 1.27
Version: 17.03.1-ee-2
MinAPIVersion: 1.12
GitCommit: ad495cb
Os: linux
GoVersion: go1.7.5
Starting build of index.docker.io/swapnil18/docker-swarm-arm-socat:latest...
Step 1/11 : FROM resin/raspberrypi3-alpine

 ---> ca84ecc9fee4

Step 2/11 : MAINTAINER Swapnil Das <dasswapnil96@gmail.com>

 ---> Running in 2a99be7f728e

 ---> e4c7fdd1bc5b

Removing intermediate container 2a99be7f728e

Step 3/11 : ARG "version=0.1.0-dev"

 ---> Running in 1019fe4333d4

 ---> d50c71235386

Removing intermediate container 1019fe4333d4

Step 4/11 : ARG "build_date=5/7/17"

 ---> Running in cbf271f27274

 ---> c9af4b356b3c

Removing intermediate container cbf271f27274

Step 5/11 : ARG "commit_hash=unknown"

 ---> Running in 1778288bf297

 ---> 35d52f36b527

Removing intermediate container 1778288bf297

Step 6/11 : ARG "vcs_url=unknown"

 ---> Running in db86bc110c3d

 ---> 9062830e7754

Removing intermediate container db86bc110c3d

Step 7/11 : ARG "vcs_branch=unknown"

 ---> Running in 919c08a0f584

 ---> 9532842acc1b

Removing intermediate container 919c08a0f584

Step 8/11 : LABEL org.label-schema.vendor "Personal" org.label-schema.name "Socat" org.label-schema.description "Exposes to a defined OUTPUT PORT the INPUT from a TCP endpoint." org.label-schema.usage "/src/README.md" org.label-schema.url "https://github.com/swapnil96/docker-swarm-arm-socat/blob/master/README.md" org.label-schema.vcs-url $vcs_url org.label-schema.vcs-branch $vcs_branch org.label-schema.vcs-ref $commit_hash org.label-schema.version $version org.label-schema.schema-version "1.0" org.label-schema.docker.cmd.devel "" org.label-schema.docker.params "IN=Input,OUT=Output" org.label-schema.build-date $build_date

 ---> Running in 641e40ae7219

 ---> 9c5d5da14397

Removing intermediate container 641e40ae7219

Step 9/11 : ENV "IN 172.18.0.1:4999" "OUT 4999"

 ---> Running in 866b338a1588

 ---> 3c046f12eb1e

Removing intermediate container 866b338a1588

Step 10/11 : RUN apk add --no-cache socat

 ---> Running in 86d0de61864f

[91mstandard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error"
[0m
Removing intermediate container 86d0de61864f

The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache socat' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

As it can be seen in the last it fails by `The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache socat' returned a non-zero code: 1`. Is the Dockerfile having some architecture issue? or there is some problem with the base image which is resin/alpine. I have build other Dockerfiles for Raspberry Pi and all have compiled fine.

For working purposes I will just push the image that is built in Raspberry Pi. But having an automated build repository is much better. So please correct me if I am doing some obvious mistake.

Here is the link to my other builds in docker hub [link](https://hub.docker.com/r/swapnil18/docker-swarm-arm-socat/builds/).

PS: I have tried other options mentioned at stackoverflow. I tried to post the links of the other questions but due to less than 10 reputation I was only given to post 2 links.

Comment: wow spent the whole day on this, same problem, my base image is "resin/rpi-raspbian:jessie" and I get error on a chmod command, did you ever find a solution ?

Comment: Looking at examples here helped me: https://github.com/alexellis/docker-arm

Comment: Haven't solved till now. I am using tags for different builds now. Automated build is moved to failed tag and I pushed images that are built in Raspberry Pi's as the latest tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because a **Raspberry Pi** runs on **arm** and docker hub does not support **arm** only **x86**, if you do wish to build the docker image on docker hub you will need to make edits to your docker image. I have done this before but it is pretty old but take a look at [resin io's work](https://github.com/resin-io-projects/armv7hf-debian-qemu) or my own customisation based off of that over [here](https://github.com/cmosh/alpine-arm). This method emulates **arm** architecture with qemu allowing the image to run natively on **arm**  devices like a **Raspberry Pi** while still having the ability to be compiled by qemu on an **x86** platform like docker hub.

Comment: See also https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/1261#issuecomment-441126749